# Python - Substition Ciphers

Tags: python, encryption

My goal of this is to have a class called cipher with three methods: A constructor, an encode method, and a decode method. This is the current format for the code I have so far:

```
class Cipher:
    def __init__(self, codestring):
        self.codestring = codestring
        alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
        for i in range(27):
            code = {a:b for (a,b) in zip(alphabet, self.codestring)}
            inverse = {a:b for (a,b) in zip(self.codestring, alphabet)}


    def encode(self, plaintext):
        self.plaintext = plaintext
        listofciphertext = [inverse[c] for c in self.plaintext]
        ciphertext = "".join(listofciphertext)
        return ciphertext


code1 = "BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA-"
code2 = "CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB-"

test1 = Cipher(code1)
test2 = Cipher(code2)

string1 = "HELLOWORLD"

#testSTR1 = (Cipher(encode(string1)))
print(test1.codestring)
print(test2.codestring)


#print(testSTR1.ciphertext)
#print(encode(code1, "IFMMPXPSME"))
```

When I attempt to run the program, it calls an error saying encode is not defined at the line which states:

```
testSTR1 = (Cipher(encode(string1)))
```

The lines after the methods are just my attempts at calling different properties of the methods to see what it returns.

I'm not sure how I should properly call the encode method in order to get it to return the encoded string. I'm also not sure if encode is even created correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `encode` using `object.encode(codestring)` (where object is an instance of `Cipher`). This will return the encoded text, which you can print using

```
print(testSTR1)
```

instead of

```
print(testSTR1.ciphertext)
```

Also to "encode" you would use `code` instead of `inverse`. `inverse` would decode the message.

Comment: This doesn't work, as testSTR1 is not properly defined.

Comment: That is what the first sentence addresses.

Comment: My problem now is that it returns an error stating 
    encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'plaintext'
Not sure how to handle it, seeing as how the positional argument should be the codestring.

Comment: +tken25 Are you using `Cipher.encode` or `test1.encode`? `test1` will work because it is an instance, but `Cipher` is the class. In the error you are getting, the `self` argument is taking the input instead of plaintext. With an instance, `self` will automatically be filled.

Comment: @pycoder I was using Cipher.encode. I used test1 and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct: there is no generic function **encode** here.  You *do* have a class method by that name, but you did not invoke that.  The usage for a class method is `instance.method(args)`.  For instance, you could perhaps use

```
test1.encode(string1)
```

You will also need to sort out your encode/decode operations, especially that you're treating **inverse** as a global variable, while it's currently local to each method (and thus undefined in encode).

---

I recommend that you drop back a bit and use incremental programming: write a few lines at a time, debug those, and don't continue until you have them working properly.  At the moment, you have several errors in different parts of your program, making it difficult to know when you're making progress.